# Issues with jQuery hide/show in Safari 5.1.10

Tags: jquery, safari, hide, show

I've seen some similar posts on my question below, but none quite hit the nail.

I have an 'update' button that I'd like to hide whilst an ajax query is executing, and replace with a loading symbol. On successful return of the ajax, I'd like things to return to normal (ie button showing and symbol hidden).

This works fine in all browsers other that Safari 5.1.10. In Safari, all other code around the jQuery hide/shows executes fine. I am also able to hide/show other elements (during other phases of the application), and if I put the same hide/show requests into the onload routine then they work fine. I'm stumped.

HTML:

```
<input id='update' type='button' value='update scores' />
<img id='update_load' src='../images/ajax-load-bar.gif' style='display:none; position:relative; left:35px; top:0px;' />
```

JQUERY:

```
function update_ES() {
  $("#update").hide();
  $("#update_load").show();
  ....
```

I can verify this lack of functionality myself in Safari 5.1.10 on Mac OS X (10.6.8) and also on an iPhone running the latest iOS 7.1. I haven't verified the same in Safari on Windows, but expect it to be so.

To elaborate... I use the following to assign the click function to 'update':

```
$('#update').click(function() {
    $("#update").hide();
    $("#update_load").show();
    switch(MC_action) {
        case "team":
            update_TS();
            break;
        case "score": case "admin":
            update_ES();
            break;
    }   
});
```

Both update_TS and update_ES are pretty similar so I'll provide update_ES as indicative of the both:

```
function update_ES() {
//hide button (temporarily) and show loading bar
$("#update").hide();
$("#update_load").show();

scores = gatherScores();
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url, 
    async: false,
    data: { scores: scores, MC_action: MC_action, match_id: match_id },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) { 
               //do some basic stuff here to process the return

               //hide loading bar, show and disable update button
       $("#update_load").hide();
       $("#update").show();
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
})
```

}

Comment: You need a blank line above code blocks, I've fixed that for you. Also, you can just select the code and click the Code Sample button or press `Ctrl+K` to have it properly shown as code without having to indent manually.

Comment: Thanks, will do in future.

Comment: Any tips for getting my post seen Fabricio?

Comment: Edit it adding your progress so far, that should bump it to the top of Active questions list.

Comment: Also, you probably didn't get answers because people didn't manage to reproduce the issue. Try to post more of your code as well, at least enough to reproduce the issue on an isolated test case.

Comment: You also didn't mention the platform you're having issues with, Safari on Windows, Mac or iOS?

Comment: Thanks, will do so now.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$('#update').click(function() {
...
}
```

to

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am confident the click function is working correctly as the appropriate sub-routine is called (ie update_TS) which happens in the switch statement inside that click function. What isn't happening is the hide and show. It's not the only instance I've seen Safari completely ignore these functions (but not fail on error either) so I'm just wondering if there is a workaround now.